# SQL PERFORMANCE - alternative to OR statement

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-azure

I am trying to optimize this sql query and I see it's using tons of OR statements throughout it, particularly again and again with the same parameter. I see if I comment out the heaviest use of it, execution time reduces by 150%.

the part I commented out looks like this for example:

```
declare @variable bit = 1
select 1 where @variable = 1 or not exists(select 1 where 1 = 2)
```

can anyone suggest a way to rewrite this without the OR ?

I am using Sql Azure

Comment: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Comment: `Select 1` will do just the same.  Is it just a part of a bigger picture?

Comment: yes bigger picture.  the issue here is not the subquery, but rather the use of the word OR.  The subquery is fast enough.  but the OR slows things down

Comment: The simplified example unfortunately won't help us. Also, `where @variable = 1`  kind of catch all queries often cause performance issues. Does it help if you create two queries depending on the value of `@variable` and execute one or the other.

Comment: What's wrong with OR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear what your query does - you simplified it too much - but you could try:

```
SELECT ... WHERE condition1
UNION
SELECT ... WHERE condition2
```

Comment: what about if I would do this?  Would this also work?  

declare variable bit = 1
select 1 where not exists(select 1 where 1 = 2 and variable =0)